# Qchart exception triggered

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt-creator

I'm developing an application that shows 3 charts in the main window and everything works fine. but now I came across an error when I make the instance
of the main window inside the class of another window the application crush and when do the debugger shows an exception triggered in one of the charts.

I used a graphic view and promote to Qchartview and for each chart the code is this:

chart_1

```
QPieSlice *slice = pieSeries->slices().at(0);
   QFont font = slice->labelFont() ;
        font.setBold(true);
        font.setPointSize(15);

        slice->setExploded();
        slice->setLabelVisible();
        slice->setPen(QPen(Qt::darkGreen, 1));
        slice->setBrush(Qt::darkBlue);
        slice->setLabelFont(font);

        QChart *chart = new QChart();
        chart->addSeries(pieSeries);
        chart->setTitle("<h2>Total money of each currency</h2>");
        chart->setAnimationOptions(QChart::SeriesAnimations);
        chart->legend()->setVisible(true);
        chart->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

        pieSeries->setLabelsVisible();
        pieSeries->setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice::LabelOutside);

        for(auto slice : pieSeries->slices())
        slice->setLabel(QString("%1%").arg(100*slice->percentage(), 0, 'f', 1));

        ui->chartView_1->setChart(chart);
        ui->chartView_1->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

chart_2

```
QChart *donutBreakdown = new QChart();
        donutBreakdown->setAnimationOptions(QChart::AllAnimations);
        donutBreakdown->setTitle("<h2>Cassettes Information</h2>");
        donutBreakdown->legend()->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);
        donutBreakdown->addSeries(series1);
        donutBreakdown->addSeries(pieSeriesPie2);
        donutBreakdown->addSeries(series3);

        pieSeriesPie2->setLabelsVisible();
        pieSeriesPie2->setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice::LabelOutside);

        double arm = 0.04;
        for(int i = 0; i < pieSeriesPie2->count(); i++){
            double arm = (double)i/24;
           double arm2= i*0.040;

                QPieSlice *slice1 = pieSeriesPie2->slices().at(i);
                slice1->setLabelArmLengthFactor(arm2);

        }
        ui->chartView_2->setChart(donutBreakdown);
        ui->chartView_2->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```

the two charts are pie chart and the triggered exception is on chart_2
I already replaced the chart_2, already replaced the graphical view that I am using in form

the days that I am fighting this error.
please help me please

Answer (score 0):

Your static_cast

```
m_slice = static_cast<CustomSlice *>(slice1);
```

is probably not working as intended. I guess you made the CustomSlice class yourself, which inherits QPieChart. Please take a look at the [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast](http://static_cast).
Did you mean dynamic_cast? Comment the line(s) out and try to reproduce the error.

Comment: this is something I am no longer using. I was trying something with customSlice.

I'll do the update